# Ubuntu TUIO touch

Tags: ubuntu, touch

I want to make my ubuntu touch(I know it already has a function for that) but what I want to do this using TUIO to send the touch events/inputs in ubuntu to another computer, anybody knows exactly how to do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking so heres the problem I am going to explain how to solve:
You have a touch surface capable of generating TUIO events, and you have an Ubuntu Machine that you want to operate with using touch.

This can be solved by using the uTouch stack in Ubuntu 12.10.

If you touch surface has a DVI / HDMI port, connect it up to the Ubuntu machine and have the display mirrored across so both displays show the same thing.

Now assuming you are able to generate TUIO events from your touch device you need to set up a few dependencies and run a script to convert these TUIO events down into native uInput.ABS_MT events which are Ubuntu's native Multitouch events.

A guide to do this can be found [here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3ajamcnaughton.wordpress.com/2012/12/14/tuio-to-utouch/)

After completing all this set up you should test the TUIO event detection by running the Tuio to Utouch script, any events detected will be printed out into the console.

After thats set up you can run the tuioToUtouch script, send in the commands --host"" --port"3333" --no-mouse-emu 
and you will be generating native Ubuntu Touch events. Unfortunately there isn't much software that uses these events, to test that this is working I'd recommend using [Kivy's TouchTracer](http://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation.html) example.

To test this you need to run the Tuio to Utouch script first, as this creates a device that will be detected by the TouchTracer, then you run the TouchTracer, make sure you run it as sudo otherwise it won't be able to listen to the device.

If you can clear up your question a bit more I could provide a more specific answer.